# How to implement template function like add(T a, K b) with std::any elegant and without template?

Tags: c++, boost, c++17

Recently, I have been reading source codes of `boost::any`,  I found that `std::any` can work fine in a virtual template member function where templates are forbidden. So, I tried to replace templates with `std::any` to implement `template<typename T, typename K> auto add(T a, K b) { return a + b; }` just with `std::any`.

Sadly, I failed.

Here is what I tried (it can only receive `(int a, int b)` and can't receive real `any` type, so it is a failure):

```
auto sum_any(std::any a, std::any b)
{
    return std::any_cast<int>(a) + std::any_cast<int>(b);
}
```

I hope to see your implementations.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
template<typename T, typename K>
auto sum_any(std::any a, std::any b)
{
    return std::any_cast<T>(a) + std::any_cast<K>(b);
}
```

the codes above con't pass compile:

> 'auto sum_any(std::any,std::any)': could not deduce template argument for 'T'('K')

Comment: Looks to me like you have hard coded type `int` with your `std::any_cast<>`. Normally this would be done with a `template<typename T>` and then use `std::any_cast<T>`. When you can say "can't reveal real `any` type" do you mean you are getting a compiler error or what? If a compiler error what is the message?

Comment: @RichardChambers In fact, I have tried std::any_cast<T> and get error, so I didn't post it here.

Comment: Right, because as the error message says, it can't deduce T and K from the argument list. You have to provide them yourself `sum_any<int, long>(a, b)`.

Comment: @czxyl: `any` is not a substitute for templates. It exists to shepherd a value between two places, such that the giver and the receiver both know what type it is, but the code in-between does not. That's what it is for.